# Let me vote to close questions from the Low Quality Posts queue

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-close, low-quality-posts

When I review low quality posts, I usually filter for answers. This means I see a lot of terrible answers. Often, those terrible answers stem from a terrible question.

Usually, I force click the link to open the whole page in a little popup window (Safari is awesome that way), which lets me triage whether this answer is a blatant copy of another one, etc. It works great for that, but I can't take action from the little popup without opening a new page.

The UI helpfully shows me the question below the answer I'm reviewing, but it doesn't give me any way to vote on it or close it. This means I have to open a new page, which is one more step.

Can we just enable the toolbar on questions (when reviewing answers) in the low quality review queue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're asked to make a decision on the answer. That's the purpose of the queue. It's great that you're paying close enough attention to recognize when a problematic answer is *inspired* by a poor question, but that still leaves open the decision of what to do about the answer itself.

As I've said elsewhere, there are *all sorts of things* that you might want to do in the context of a post that comes up in review. And you *always* have the ability to break out of review and do them. But it's not practical to put those options in front of you *in review itself*; they're essentially distractions, and while you're distracted you're holding up the decision on the post that urgently needs it.

Make a call on the answer and then open up the question and do whatever else your heart desires.